# Multiple wget to save multiple local files with naming convention

Tags: php, xml, rss, cron, wget

**Summary**
I am on a PHP news crawler project and want to pull RSS news feeds from nearly a hundred of news websites using wget (version 1.12) to capture whole RSS feed files, all in one directory (without hierarchy) in local server regarding:

- Some of these websites **do not have RSS feed** and so I should capture and parse their `HTML`, but at the beginning I can just concentrate on XML feeds.
- All feed files from all websites **in one directory**.
- **No extra content** should be downloaded. all extra content (like images if any) should be hosted on the remote.
- Performance is important
- Feed files **need to be renamed** before save according to my convention like `source.category.type.xml` (each XML remote URL has its own source, category and type but not with my naming convention)
- Some of these feeds **do not include news timestamp** like with `<pubDate>` and so I have to choose a good working approach to handle news time even with a slight difference but robust, working and always functional.
- To automate it, I need to perform a cron job on this wget on regular basis

`url-list.txt` includes:

```
http://source1/path/to/rss1  
http://source2/diiferent/path/to/rss2  
http://source3/path/to/rss3  
.  
.  
.  
http://source100/different/path/to/rss100
```

I want this:

```
localfeed/source1.category.type.xml  
localfeed/source2.category.type.xml  
localfeed/source3.category.type.xml  
.  
.  
.  
localfeed/source100.category.type.xml
```

Category and type can have multiple predefined values like `sport`, ...

---

**What do I have?**
At the very first level I should do my `wget` using a list of remote URLs: According to [this wget instructions](http://www.rootr.net/man/info/wget):

1. `url-list.txt` should consist of a series of URLs, one per line
2. When running `wget` without `-N`, `-nc`, `-r`, or `-p`, downloading the same file in the same directory will result in the original copy of `FILE` being preserved and the second copy being named `FILE.1`.
3. Use of `-O` like `wget -O FILE` is *not* intended to mean simply "use the name FILE instead of the one in the URL". It outputs the whole downloads into just **one** file.
4. Use `-N` for time stamping
5. `-w SECONDS` will hold on for `SECONDS` seconds of time before next retrieval
6. `-nd` forces `wget` not to create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.  With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the filenames will get extensions `.n')
7. `-nH` disables generation of host-prefixed directories (the behavior which `-r` by default does).
8. `-P PREFIX` sets directory prefix to PREFIX.  The "directory prefix" is the directory where all other files and subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree.
9. `-k` converts links for offline browsing

   ```
   $ wget -nH -N -i url-list.txt
   ```

---

**Issues** with (wget & cron job and php):

1. How to handle news time? is it better to save timestamp in file names like `source.category.type.timestamp.xml` or fetch change time using `php`s `stat` function like this:

   ```
   $stat = stat('source.category.type.xml');
   $time = $stat('mtime');     //last modification time
   ```

   or any other ideas (which is always working and robust)
2. How to handle file names? I want to save files locally on a distinct convention (`source.category.type.xml`) and so I think `wget options` like `--trust-server-names` or `--content-disposition` could not help. I think I should go to a while loop like this:

   ```
   while read url; do
     wget -nH -N -O nameConvention $url
   done < utl-list.txt
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to stay away from wget for your task as it makes your life really complicated for no reason. PHP is perfectly fine to fetch downloads.

I would add all URLs into a database (it might be just a text file, like in your case). Then I would use a cronjob to trigger the script.
On each run I would check a fixed number of sites and put their RSS feeds into the folder. E.g. with `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` you are good to go. This allows you full control over what to fetch and how to save it.

The I would use another script that goes over the files and does the parsing. Separating the scripts from beginning will help you to scale later on.
For a simple site, just sorting the files by `mtime` should do the trick. For a big scaleout, I would use a jobqueue.

The overhead in PHP is minimal while the additional complexity by using wget is a big burden.